# MySql IN condition between two set of data

Tags: mysql

I want to do a MySql query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (1, 2, 3) IN (SELECT ...)
```

I need to test if one value of the first set (1, 2, 3) is IN the second SELECT.

How I can do this operation?

Comment: _I need to test if one value of the first set (1, 2, 3) is IN the second SELECT_ > Didn't get this ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. You must define at least 1 field in your WHERE criteria. For example :

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
WHERE field_a IN (1, 2, 3)  
      and field_a IN (SELECT field_a from table_b)
```

Make sure `field_a` in `table_a` is same data type with `(1,2,3)` and `field_a` in `table_b`